# How can one fill an area in checkered pattern?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to fill certain area(2d or 3d) in checkered pattern, using commands(`/fill`, `/clone`, etc) and vanilla mechanics?

The number of commands must remain constant regardless of the number of blocks to fill.

Comment: A 2-d area or a 3-d area?

Comment: @Studoku Any dimension.

Comment: Fill a small area manually and then clone it.

Comment: Would a few command on a clock be fine, or does it need to be a single command or run in chat?

Comment: @colorfusion It doesn't matter but should be infinitely expandable(under command limit) without adding additional commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Just use MCEdit

That'll be way easier for you.

---

### Vanilla way (a lot of work)

You could fill with any pattern by using a scoreboard counter (fake player + dummy objective, decrement to count, check each tick if it's above 0. If so, run the following command[You can do this in 1.9 using conditionals, 1.8 using an entity instead of the fake player]) **I will show you the 1.8 way, since this WILL work in 1.9, it's just slightly less efficient and a bit less intuitive.**

---

**Run once to set up:**

1> /summon ArmorStand {CustomName:"CounterX"}
2> /summon ArmorStand {CustomName:"CounterY"}
3> /summon ArmorStand {CustomName:"CounterZ"}
4> /scoreboard objectives add vars dummy
5> /summon ArmorStand    {CustomName:"startPoint", NoGravity:1}
6> /scoreboard players set @e[name=CounterX] vars 
7> /scoreboard players set @e[name=CounterY] vars 
8> /scoreboard players set @e[name=CounterX] vars 
9> /scoreboard players set @e[name=startPoint] vars 1

---

**Run in a fill clock:**

1> /execute @e[name=CounterX,score_vars_min=1] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[name=startPoint,score_vars=1] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~2[or another size pattern] ~ ~ {CustomName:"startPoint", NoGravity:1}
2> /scoreboard players add @e[name=startPoint] vars 1
3> /scoreboard players remove @e[name=CounterX] vars 1

Break the clock after completion

---

**Run once after that stops doing anything:**
1> /scoreboard players set @e[name=startPoint] vars 1

---

**Run in a fill clock:**

1> /execute @e[name=CounterZ,score_vars_min=1] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[name=startPoint,score_vars=1] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~2[or another size pattern] {CustomName:"startPoint", NoGravity:1}
2> /scoreboard players add @e[name=startPoint] vars 1
3> /scoreboard players remove @e[name=CounterZ] vars 1

Break the clock after completion

---

**Run once after that stops doing anything:**
1> /scoreboard players set @e[name=startPoint] vars 1

---

**Run in a fill clock:**

1> /execute @e[name=CounterY,score_vars_min=1] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[name=startPoint,score_vars=1] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~2[or another size pattern] ~ {CustomName:"startPoint", NoGravity:1}
2> /scoreboard players add @e[name=startPoint] vars 1
3> /scoreboard players remove @e[name=CounterY] vars 1

Break the clock after completion

---

**Run once**
1>  /execute @e[name=startPoint] clone [x1OfPattern] [y1OfPattern] [z1OfPattern] [x2OfPattern] [y2OfPattern] [z2OfPattern] ~ ~ ~
2>  /kill @e[name=startPoint]

---

**And you're done! If I typed everything properly, that should work. I would make this a one-command-block thing, but it's too late for that**
(Wow, that was a huge post)

Comment: Thank you very much for your hard work. That is much more complicated than I anticipated.

Comment: That's why I suggested the use of mcedit :P

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the clone command, which is probably easier.

Make your pattern, find the bottom left corner of your pattern coordinates and the top right corner of your pattern coordinates.

Then, find the bottom left corner of where you want to put the pattern.

Your command looks like this:

```
/clone <insert bottom left pattern x y z here> <insert bottom right pattern x y z here> <insert bottom left new location x y z here>
```

That should work. You can find your coordinates using f3 or alt+f3.